# Checking role exists for user before add

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, roles

I am trying to add roles for user but before that i want to check it is exists or not. How Can i do that?
Here is my code

```
  public void AddRoleForUser(ApplicationUser obj, IdentityRole role)
    {
        _userManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(_context));

        var currentUser = _userManager.FindById(obj.Id);
        // before this i have to check 
        var roleresult = _userManager.AddToRole(currentUser.Id, role.Name);
    }
```

for example i have a user and its id =1. When i add role for this user i want to check there is a role for this user before add new role to this user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to check `User.IsInRole("YourRoleName");`

If you want to check by **`User Id`**, use the code below.

```
if (!userManager.IsInRole(user.Id, "Admin"))
{
    userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Admin");
}
```

Comment: I'm so glad to know that it's helped you :) Cheers

Comment: i am write this query in simple controller not a web api controller used for that then how can use UserManger in this controller?