# how to get role in web api mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I try to fetch all the roles using web api but didn't get any role.
I want all roles by user wise. But I'm unable to get any role in my query. Can you help me what is problems.

here this my code :

```
var res = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser("abc.com").FirstOrDefault();
var r = System.Web.Security.Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList();
```

i have try this code write but did't getting any role in my database i have added role and also add role for this 'abc.com' user.

Comment: What about `User.IsInRole("RoleName")`?

Comment: i am try also this User.IsInRole("Admin") but getting false but i my db Admin role is available.

Comment: then after i m add this code ' <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>  ' in web.config then getting error like this 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.aspnet_SchemaVersions'.'

Comment: Is the user you are trying to get the role of authenticated (logged-In)?

Comment: yes authenticated user.

Comment: Can you confirm what security framework you are using?  How are you adding users to their respective roles?  You talk about having records (roles) in the database already - which roles, and show us what the records in these tables look like.

Comment: for ex : this table store AspNetRoles  "id for guid","Admin" and this table store AspNetUserRoles "userid","id for guid" like this data store in table

Comment: now i am fire query and using username don't get admin role in res variable. @basanta matia can you please help me for that query

Comment: @coderwill check my post here. I already solved that http://stackoverflow.com/a/42719406/2376652

Comment: @BasantaMatia but this your solution is check the user is in role or not i want to role name using username so how can do that.;

Comment: @BasantaMatia i am write query his not give any error but don't get role name. my username is 'abc.com' is a "Admin" role assign then i want to admin in res var.

Comment: Check this UserManager.FindByName(Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()).Roles; OR UserManager.FindByName("YourUserName").Roles; Let me know

Comment: @BasantaMatia I am write this query in simple controller so UserManager is not getting current context so how can fix it?

Comment: @BasantaMatia i am write this query in simple controller not a web api controller used for that then how can use UserManger in this controller?

Comment: First confirm me whether u want all the roles using web api or MVC project ?? You have mentioned in your question its Web Api. In ur comment u mentioned MVC

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140052/discussion-between-coderwill-and-basanta-matia).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your comment above, you are trying to get the role by user in a simple **Controller** method not Api Controller. So check my code below.

Suppose your Controller name is **AdminController**, then there add these code below.

```
public class AdminController : Controller
{
 //rest code
 private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;

 public AdminController()
 {
 }

 public AdminController(ApplicationUserManager userManager)
 {
    UserManager = userManager;
 }
 public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
 {
    get
     {
      return _userManager ?? 
      HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
      }
    private set
      {
       _userManager = value;
      }
  }
  //then rest code, what ever you have 

  //Add this bellow code inside the Method, where you want to fetch the 
  //roles by username
  var myRoles = UserManager.FindByName("nirav@gmail.com").Roles;
  //then rest code
```

And yes, you need to add the reference

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
```

That's it!